# Android EditText: Expand upwards

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext

My EditText is expanding downwards when the input has too many characters, which leads to it being hidden behind other elements, like the keyboard. I want the user to be able to see the save and delete buttons which I have layed out below the TextView, even when a long message gets entered.

Is there any way to get the EditText to expand upwards instead of downwards?

For example, in Whatsapp entering long messages leads to the input field expanding upwards and eventually starting to scroll.

Comment: Please post some some code, like your layout, and maybe a screenshot illustrating the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i figured the porblem , the adjustpin of the soft key is not working on full secreen mode .